# Array (Inside of a String) Conversion, Swift 4

Tags: swift4

Does anyone know the simplest way to convert an Array inside of a String to an actual Array without effecting any characters?

For Example:

```
var array: [String] = []
let myStr = "[\"Hello,\", \"World\"]"
// I would like 'array' to store: ["Hello,", "World"]
```

I thought it could be done with `Array(myStr)` but that would only make an array of all the characters.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode it with [`JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder), since it is a JSON.

Example below:

```
let myStr = "[\"Hello,\", \"World\"]"
let data = Data(myStr.utf8)

do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
    print("Decoded:", decoded)
} catch {
    fatalError("Error")
}

// Prints:   Decoded: ["Hello,", "World"]
```

What is happening:

1. Your `myStr` string is converted to `Data`.
2. This data is then decoded as `[String]` - which is an array of strings.
3. The decoded data of type `[String]` is then printed.

We use a do-try-catch pattern to catch errors, such as incorrect format or data entered.